# not able to create combinations of arrays with java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to create different combinations from multiple sized arrays, picking one element from each.
check below code, collect variable is giving correct output, but collect1 is giving error.

```
int[] pants= {3, 5, 7}, shirts = {4, 7, 8}, 
                skirts = {5, 8}, shoes = {3};

List<int[]> collect = Arrays.stream(pants)
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(shirts)
            .mapToObj(j -> new int[] {i,j}))
            
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<int[]> collect1 = Arrays.stream(pants)
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(shirts)
            .mapToObj(j -> Arrays.stream(skirts)
            .mapToObj(k -> Arrays.stream(shoes)
            .mapToObj(l -> new int[] {i,j,k,l}))))
            
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

collect.forEach(ar->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar)));
```

error for collect1 is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Stream<Stream<int[]>>> to List<int[]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often a good idea to reduce a problem to the smallest for possible. Here it is 2 lists with 2 items. Combining them means to take the first item of the first list and then produce a combination with each each of the second list. Then take the second item of the first list and combine it with each item from the second list. And so on …

Pseudo code:

```
combine({1, 2}, {3, 4}) == { { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 } };
```

Now let's try to express this with streams:

```
int[] first = { 1, 2 }, second = { 3, 4 };

int[][] combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .map(b -> new int[]{a, b}))
        .toArray();
```

The tricky part is, that this does not work! Streams (and generics in general) in Java can only used reference types, they do not support simple value types such as `int`. This makes the code a bit more complicated. The type `int[]` extends `Object`, so we can transform the code as follows:

```
Object[] combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .mapToObj(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .mapToObj(b -> new int[]{a, b}))
        .flatMap(x -> x)
        .toArray();
```

Adding a third input array makes this:

```
Object[] combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .mapToObj(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .mapToObj(b -> Arrays.stream(third)
                        .mapToObj(c -> new int[]{a, b, c}))
                .flatMap(x -> x))
        .flatMap(x -> x)
        .toArray();
```

or, with a list of int arrays:

```
List<int[]> combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .mapToObj(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .mapToObj(b -> Arrays.stream(third)
                        .mapToObj(c -> new int[]{a, b, c}))
                .flatMap(x -> x))
        .flatMap(x -> x)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Rinse and repeat, until you have added all inputs:

```
List<int[]> combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .mapToObj(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .mapToObj(b -> Arrays.stream(third)
                        .mapToObj(c -> Arrays.stream(fourth).mapToObj(d -> new int[]{a, b, c, d}))
                        .flatMap(x -> x))
                .flatMap(x -> x))
        .flatMap(x -> x)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you were to start out with boxed Integers, your stream would become a lot simpler:

```
Integer[] first = { 1, 2 }, second = { 3, 4 }, third = { 5, 6 }, fourth = { 7, 8 };

List<int[]> combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .flatMap(b -> Arrays.stream(third)
                        .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(fourth)
                                .map(d -> new int[]{a, b, c, d}))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A similar effect can be achieved by converting each `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` first. I find this is easier to read and understand than the mapToObj.flatMap style:

```
List<int[]> combinations = Arrays.stream(first)
        .boxed()
        .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(second)
                .boxed()
                .flatMap(b -> Arrays.stream(third)
                        .boxed()
                        .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(fourth)
                                .boxed()
                                .map(d -> new int[]{a, b, c, d}))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Be aware of the performance impact when creating lots of nested and small streams and when boxing/unboxing primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for `MapToObj`: "Returns an object-valued Stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream."

So every time you call it, it returns a `Stream`. Thus if you want just the values in the stream, you must add in a call to `flatmap` for every call to `MapToObj`:

```
List<int[]> collect1 = Arrays.stream(pants)
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(shirts)
          .mapToObj(j -> Arrays.stream(skirts)
            .mapToObj(k -> Arrays.stream(shoes)
              .mapToObj(l -> new int[] {i,j,k,l}))))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```